# Why is my maven surefire plugin getting ignored?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I created a maven project in Netbeans 7.3 using the Maven Plugin for Netbeans (v4.20.1)

In my pom.xml, I try to explicitly define the surefire plugin, but no matter what I do it never picks it up.  It is pulling a different version of surefire (2.10), and I'm not sure from where.  All other plugins in the pom.xml work as expected. Any clues?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>myVersion</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>myName</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>        
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
                <!-- This invalid version should trigger a maven error, but doesn't -->
                <version>92.14</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin> 

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>            

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <!--etc...-->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <!--etc...-->
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
            <!--etc...-->
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact you referenced (`org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire`) is not a plugin, it's a POM.

You should change the declaration using :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
        </plugin>
```